# html/css : how do I make <p>s inside a <div> have different properties

Tags: html, css

I want a box that contains two "paragraphs" with different colors. I wrote :

```
    <div>
    <p>Red</p>
    <p>Green<p>
    </div>
```

and css:

```
    div{
    color:red;
    background-color : grey;
    height : 50px;
    width : 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border : solid black 3px;
    font-size : 30px;
    border-radius : 15px;
    }
```

div:nth-child(2) {
color:green
}`

It doesn't work : everything in the div is red.
What should I do?

Comment: use `div p:nth-child(2) { color:green }`

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this `p:nth-child(2) { color:green }`

```css
 div{
    color:red;
    background-color : grey;
    height : 50px;
    width : 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border : solid black 3px;
    font-size : 30px;
    border-radius : 15px;
    }
div p:nth-child(2) { color:green }
```

```html
<div>
    <p>Red</p>
    <p>Green<p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it like this:

In your css create two classes one called Red and the other Green

```
.green{
    color: green;
}
 .red{
    color: red;
}
```

Then in you html you just call the class by adding something like

```
<p class="green"></p>
<p class="red"></p>
```

Comment: Thnk you for your answer! I mixed up nth-child with containers and now it works

Comment: Which solution did you use?

Answer (score 0):

A ***simple way*** to do what you want is to put it into another div

**HTML**

```
<div class="clase">
  <div class="subclase">
    <p>Red</p>
  </div>
  <p>Green<p>
</div>
```

then assign css properties to `subclase`, or to the `<p>` inside it.

To give some diferent properties to the `<p>` inside `subclase` than any other `<p>` div, you can write it in your css like [this (check the link)](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp) :

**CSS**

```
div p {[PROPERTY HERE];} /*this will apply to Red and Green.*/
subclase p {ANOTHER PROPERTY;} /*this  line would override any 
                                  property only for Red*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I would give your parent div an id and then enter the css accordingly.

HTML:

```
<div id="parent-div">
    <p>Red</p>
    <p>Green<p>
</div>
```

CSS (The "div" is unchanged):

```
div {
    color:red;
    background-color : grey;
    height : 50px;
    width : 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border : solid black 3px;
    font-size : 30px;
    border-radius : 15px;
}

#parent-div p {
    color: green;
}
```